# Is it possbile to stream video to a server using an esp32 cam?

Tags: server, video-streaming, client, esp32

I need to stream video data to a server from an ESP32-cam. So I need to set the esp32-cam as a client, but I could not find any example code or any resource regarding how to stream video data to a server. There are example that show how to set ESP32-cam as a video streaming server, but not client. I could not find any resource. Is this possible at all?
Or as an alternative solution, would it be possible to connect the esp32-cam server to another server?
I would appreciate if you could give any resources.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean you want the camera to act like an IP-Camera and send its stream to a server so you can then stream the video from that server.

Many servers for IP cameras will be set up to receive RTSP streams - there are example libraries to send a RTSP stream from your esp32-cam which you can use for this. One popular example: https://github.com/geeksville/Micro-RTSP

As a note, you could also have your server act as a client when you esp32-cam acts as a streaming server. It could then re-stream the video to wherever ever you want to send it.